# How to Remove 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll where server returned an error code of (500)

Tags: c#, rest, file-upload, webclient

I am using webclient to upload my files to server via Rest Service. I am checking my code by debugging it on a local host what I found is my server is successfully receiving all these files but at client end where I have a code for sending file I am getting this exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>
> **Additional information**: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

The code I am using is below:

```
var Filereqparam = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
using (var lWebClient = new WebClient()) {                      
    foreach (var file in data.file) {
        Filereqparam.Add("FileName", file.FileName);
        Filereqparam.Add("FileExtension", file.FileExtension);
        Filereqparam.Add("FileData", file.FileData);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( Filereqparam);
               
        var recvFiledata = lWebClient.UploadValues("http://localhost:56156/api/userfiles/getfiles", Filereqparam);
                   
        var respFileBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvFiledata);
    }
}
```

I have set the time limit for client to unlimited, but still I am unable to resolve this issue. My question is why I am receiving this exception if my files are successfully sent to server?

> Note: If anyone know a better way to upload the large files to server via rest service then please share your technique.

Comment: Are you sure you have returned the correct status code? can u share server code..

Comment: Yup i am sure, i have reviewed my code soo many times.

Comment: Try to return what your calling method is expecting.

Comment: But the problem seems to be on that part.

Comment: Are you able to debug the rest service? You should debug and check what's going on there to cause error? It's not the problem of client code for sure. It's the service which has something not right.